# What is the difference between "named" and "termed"?

Tags: word-choice

I have the following two sentences:

(1) This new index was termed *relative correlation*.

(2) This new index was named *relative correlation*.

Which is better?  Or how to make a choice between "named" and "termed"?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well! a name is a term. In fact, all words are term, but vice-verse is not true.

Comment: [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/199409?rskey=m0wpSF&result=1#eid) definition is useful, I think. Term : more widely: any word or phrase _expressing a particular idea or concept_, or denoting a particular object; an expression (for something). Often with modifying word or phrase, as abstract term, general term, term of abuse, term of endearment, etc.

Comment: Choice and style Questions don't belong here, but broadly, "Named" is clearly what you meant and would never be open to any challenge… and alwys comes from the inventor/producer/supplier.

"Termed" *could* serve a similar purpose but might almost as likely be used in challenge, query or derision.

Umpteen further queries apply, but not here…

Answer (score -1):

It is based purely on preference. However, depending on what or who you are writing for, one could be preferred over the other.

> Name means give a name to or specify (a sum, time, or place) as something desired, suggested, or decided on.
>
> Term means to give a descriptive name to; call by a specified term.

If it something technical like a documentation or thesis, termed may be better.

> i.e. Washington termed our endless and thankless task counterinsurgency—and Anbaris made good insurgents, very good insurgents.

For something less technical or light-hearted named would be better.

> i.e. The dead man has been named as John Mackintosh.

Answer (score -1):

**named**, as defined by [Cambridge Dict.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/named):

> to give someone or something a name:

**termed**, as defined by [Cambridge Dict.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/termed):

> to give something a name or to describe it with a particular expression

The **particular expression** here doesn't seem too specific. Let's see what [MW has to say about this word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/term):

> to apply a **term*** to
>
> ***term**: a word or expression that has a precise meaning in some uses or
>   is peculiar to a science, art, profession, or subject

The two words are very similar in terms of meaning: they both can be used to describe the action of giving something a name. However, **termed** is much more formal and is often used to describe very specific concepts in multiple different fields. **named**, on the other hand, is a bit less formal and thus, much less restrictive than **termed**.

The general consensus seems to be: if you want to give a name to a very specific concept in a formal environment, pick **termed**. If you want to name just about everything in a non-formal, or semi-formal setting, choose **named**.